Expression to check the current date if equal to specific date provided in the expression
I want to condition is the current date is 16th or 17th of month using expression. This is having syntax error. Can anyone help me create a expression if current date is some specific date i want to check
`{
    "and": [
        {
           "or":[ 
            "equals": [
                "2024-07-16",
                "@formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')"
            ],
            "equals": [
                "2024-07-17",
                "@formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')"
            ]
           ]
        }
    ]
}`


It seems you have mixed up square and curly brackets somewhere...
Here, check this out:
{
    "and": [
        {
            "or": [
                {
                    "equals": [
                        "@formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')",
                        "2024-07-16"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "equals": [
                        "@formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')",
                        "2024-07-17"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

But I think this expression could be used for checking if the current date is the 16th or 17th of the month:
{
    "and": [
        {
            "or": [
                {
                    "equals": [
                        "@dayOfMonth(utcNow())",
                        16
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "equals": [
                        "@dayOfMonth(utcNow())",
                        17
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

